# Why does this Java 8 method reference compile?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I'm currently diving deeper into `Java 8` features like Lambdas and method references. Playing around a bit brought me to the following example:

```
public class ConsumerTest {

  private static final String[] NAMES = {"Tony", "Bruce", "Steve", "Thor"};

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Arrays.asList(NAMES).forEach(Objects::requireNonNull);
   }
}
```

*My question is:*

Why does the line inside the main method compile ?

If I understood the thing correctly, the referenced method's signature has to correspond to the functional interface's SAM signature. In this case, the Consumer requires the following signature:

```
void accept(T t);
```

However, the `requireNonNull` method returns `T` instead of void:

```
public static <T> T requireNonNull(T obj)
```

Comment: Consider `myList.forEach(myOtherList::add)`. Do you ever care that `List.add` returns `boolean` which is always `true`? It would be a pain if `myOtherList::add` doesn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Java Language Specification version 8 says in [15.13.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2):

> A method reference expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context with a target type T if T is a functional interface type ([§9.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.9)) and the expression is congruent with the function type of the ground target type derived from T.
>
> [..]
>
> A method reference expression is congruent with a function type if both of the following are true:
>
> - The function type identifies a single compile-time declaration corresponding to the reference.
> - One of the following is true:
>
>   - **The result of the function type is void.**
>   - The result of the function type is R, and the result of applying capture conversion ([§5.1.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10)) to the return type of the invocation type ([§15.12.2.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.6)) of the chosen compile-time declaration is R' (where R is the target type that may be used to infer R'), and neither R nor R' is void, and R' is compatible with R in an assignment context.

(emphasis mine)

So the fact the result of the function type is void, is enough for it to allow it to match.

[JLS 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) also specifically mentions the use of void when matching methods. For lambda expression there is the notion of a *void-compatible* block ([15.27.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2)) which is referenced in [15.12.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1), but there is no equivalent definition for method references.

I haven't been able to find a more specific explanation (but the JLS is a tough nut to crack so maybe I am missing some relevant sections), but I assume this has to do with the fact that you are also allowed to invoke non-void methods as a statement on its own (without assignment, `return` etc)).

[JLS 15.13.3 Run-Time Evaluation of Method References](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3) also says:

> For the purpose of determining the compile-time result, the method invocation expression is an expression statement if the invocation method's result is void, and the Expression of a return statement if the invocation method's result is non-void.
>
> *The effect of this determination when the compile-time declaration of the method reference is signature polymorphic is that:*
>
> - *The types of the parameters for the method invocation are the types of the corresponding arguments.*
> - *The method invocation is either void or has a return type of Object, depending on whether the invocation method which encloses the method invocation is void or has a return type.*

So the generated method invocation will be void to match the functional type.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from what it says in @Mark Rotteveel's exact answer, it compiles because in Java you can ignore the result of any method invocation, such as in the following example:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("1", "a");

map.put("1", "A"); // Who cares about the returned value "a"?
```

As you're not returning anything in the `forEach()` consumer's block, then it is valid as per the specification.